# How to ignore signal for first 50 seconds?

Tags: c++, signals

```
void signal_handler(int signo)
{
    struct sigaction act;

    if ((sigaction(signo, NULL, &act) == -1) || (act.sa_handler != SIG_IGN))
    {
        alarm(50);
    }

}

int main()
{
    sigaction(SIGINT,signal_handler);
    sigaction(SIGALAM,signal_handler);
    alarm(50);

    while (1)
    {
    }
     return 0;
}
```

I want to ignore Ctrl + C signal for first 50 seconds. I tried it with alarm but its not ignoring the signals.

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps you need to follow to acheive your ends:

- Set `SIGINT` to `SIG_IGN` when `main` starts.
- Then set `SIGALARM` to call a *different* handler (after 50 seconds).
- In that handler, change `SIGINT` so that it now points to the actual handler.

This should ignore `SIGINT` interrupts for the first fifty seconds or so, then act on them afterwards.

---

Here's a complete program that shows this in action. It basically performs the steps detailed above but with slight modifications for a test program:

- Start ignoring `INT`.
- Set `ALRM` to activate after ten seconds.
- Start generating `INT` signals every second for twenty seconds.
- When alarm activated, stop ignoring `INT`.

The program is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

static time_t base, now; // Used for tracking time.

// Signal handlers.

void int_handler(int unused) {
    // Just log the event.

    printf("  - Handling INT at t=%ld\n", now - base);
}

void alarm_handler(int unused) {
    // Change SIGINT handler from ignore to actual.

    struct sigaction actn;
    actn.sa_flags = 0;
    actn.sa_handler = int_handler;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &actn, NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    base = time(0);

    struct sigaction actn;

    // Initially ignore INT.

    actn.sa_flags = 0;
    actn.sa_handler = SIG_IGN;
    sigaction(SIGINT, &actn, NULL);

    // Set ALRM so that it enables INT handling, then start timer.

    actn.sa_flags = 0;
    actn.sa_handler = alarm_handler;
    sigaction(SIGALRM, &actn, NULL);
    alarm(10);

    // Just loop, generating one INT per second.

    for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        now = time(0);
        printf("Generating INT at t=%ld\n", now - base);
        raise(SIGINT);
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output on my box so you can see it in action, ignoring `INT` signals for the first ten seconds, then acting on them:

```
Generating INT at t=0
Generating INT at t=1
Generating INT at t=2
Generating INT at t=3
Generating INT at t=4
Generating INT at t=5
Generating INT at t=6
Generating INT at t=7
Generating INT at t=8
Generating INT at t=9
Generating INT at t=10
  - Handling INT at t=10
Generating INT at t=11
  - Handling INT at t=11
Generating INT at t=12
  - Handling INT at t=12
Generating INT at t=13
  - Handling INT at t=13
Generating INT at t=14
  - Handling INT at t=14
Generating INT at t=15
  - Handling INT at t=15
Generating INT at t=16
  - Handling INT at t=16
Generating INT at t=17
  - Handling INT at t=17
Generating INT at t=18
  - Handling INT at t=18
Generating INT at t=19
  - Handling INT at t=19
```

Comment: do I need to make any changes in `void signal_handler(int signo)`?

Comment: @Saurabh, added some code to hopefully make it clearer. Enjoy :-)

Comment: thank you, here I have a doubt what if I want to perform some action after 50 seconds , how do I do that?

Comment: I run this code without for loop and its just ended.I need something like it should exit after 500 sec.(alive for 500 sec) but should ignore CTRL+C signal for first 50 seconds

Comment: @Saurabh, that's a *demo* program based on your original question, it shows you exactly how to ignore `INT` for the first *n* seconds of your program, which is what you requested. If you have a *different* question, you should generally ask it as a different question. FWIW, you could simply retask the alarm signal for exiting your program as well.

Comment: Not really, because it changes the nature of the question, most likely invalidating answers given to date. While you're certainly within your rights to do so, it's considered by many to be anti-social in terms of the SO community. In any case, Joel et al have plenty of disk space for more questions :-)

Comment: lol he have disk space but I dont have time :) anyways thank you